# INSERT INTO table1 values FROM table2 WHERE

Tags: php, sql

I've looked around nothing seems to be working for me. I have a button when pushed it INSERTS data into 1 table-1, then it gets values from table-3 to put in table-2 where in they the ID is the same.

```
        if ($movieTime != "") {
        $query = "SELECT SchedID FROM tblCinemaSched WHERE TheaterID='$tid' AND CinemaID='$cid' AND MovieDate='$date' AND MovieTime='$movieTime'";
        //echo "$query<br>";
        $result=$conn->executeUpdate($query);
        $numRows=$conn->numRows($result);
        if ($numRows<=0) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO tblCinemaSched SET TheaterID='$tid', CinemaID='$cid', MovieDate='$date', MovieTime='$movieTime', MovieID='$movieId', PriceAmt='$priceId', CrtBy='$username', CrtDate=NOW()";
            //echo "$query<br>";
            $result=$conn->executeUpdate($query);
            //get seat defaults from tblCSeats
            $query = "INSERT INTO tblSSeats SELECT TheaterID,  CinemaID, '$date', '$movieTime', SeatID, RowNo, ColumnNo, Handicap, Status, LeftSeat, RightSeat, NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$username',NOW() FROM tblCSeats WHERE TheaterID='$tid' AND CinemaID='$cid'";
            //echo "$query<br>";
            $result=$conn->executeUpdate($query);

            $errorStr   = "Succesfully added schedule.";
        }
        else {
            $errorStr   = "There's already an existing schedule for the specified time.";
        }
```

You see tableCSeats has more than 1 row that has the same ID meaning I want to insert multiple data from tableCSeats to tableSSeats. tableSSeats is a has no data in it yet.

Comment: so what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Successfully added schedule. I did add my schedule in my first query but, the second query doesn't work.

Comment: mysql_insert_id(); what is this line doing

Comment: I'm sorry i deleted that already.. I'll edit that part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a blind guess, it would seem that you are looking for [**`INSERT ... SELECT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Comment: Thanks. My query was wrong. Though the format helped, the root of my problem was my tables in INSERT INTO was lacking one table. I saw this when I used your suggested INSERT ... SELECT statement thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the return values of your queries. You always get "Succesfully added schedule." because you don't check if the queries were succesful. Ex:

```
if(!$result=$conn->executeUpdate($query)) {
    die('error');
}
```

or something like that.